# Pandas create time series from day counts

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a data frame consisting of many days of time series data of aggregate counts of website clicks sampled periodically throughout the day. The count resets to zero on each new day. So at the end of the first day, the count has reached 9 clicks. Then on day 2, the count starts again at 0 and at has reached 8 clicks by the end of the day...etc

```
day    value    time
------------------------
1        0      00:45:00
1        5      02:15:00
1        8      06:55:00
1        9      13:10:00
2        0      00:10:00
2        1      01:00:00
2        7      05:15:00     
2        8      11:45:00 
3        0      03:00:00
3        4      07:30:00
3        7      15:30:00
```

I want to aggregate the separate days together to form one cumulative time series over all the days.

```
day    value    time
------------------------
1        0      00:45:00
1        5      02:15:00
1        8      06:55:00
1        9      13:10:00
2        9      00:10:00
2        10     01:00:00
2        16     05:15:00     
2        17     11:45:00 
3        17     03:00:00
3        21     07:30:00
3        24     15:30:00
```

Does Pandas have a way to do this efficiently?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It doesn't look like your aggregating anything. Check your expected output and explain how you got those values.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Tom. At the end of day 1, the value count is up to 9, so then I want day 2 to start counting from 9, like in the second output, as opposed to zero, like in the first. I'll edit the question to read more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really asking about contigiuous groups (rather than the standard groupby, which ignores whether items in the same group are neighbouring) so I think you need to use diff:

```
In [11]: df['day'].diff().astype(bool)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: day, dtype: bool
```

*Note: the NaN is converted to True! also the `astype(bool)` isn't strictly necessary if you can guarantee that each group is non-empty and increasing by each time.*

You can then multiply this by the corresponding (last) value:

```
In [12]: previous = (df.day.diff() * df['value'].shift())

In [13]: previous
Out[13]:
0   NaN
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     9
5     0
6     0
7     8
8     0
9     0
dtype: float64
```

I would probably just set the first value to 0 (you could use `fillna(0)` as a one-liner):

```
In [14]: previous.iloc[0] = 0
```

Now, adding the cumsum of this gets you the result you're after:

```
In [15]: df['value'] + previous.cumsum()
Out[15]:
0     0
1     5
2     8
3     9
4    10
5    16
6    17
7    17
8    21
9    24
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'day':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 , 3, 3, 3],\
                'value':[0 ,5 ,8 ,9 ,1 ,7 ,8 ,0 ,4 ,7]})
# Evaluate the offset to add
dd=df.groupby('day').max().cumsum()
df.set_index('day',inplace=True)
# Creation of offset dataframe
dd.index += 1
# Delete the last row
dd=dd[0:-1]
# Evaluate the first row
dd=dd.append(pd.DataFrame({'value':[0]},index=[df.index[0]]))
# Perform the addition
df = df.add(dd)
```

Resulting in

```
   value
1      0
1      5
1      8
1      9
2     10
2     16
2     17
3     17
3     21
3     24
```